# Can't run demos of Qt

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu-12.04

I just installed Qt. I tried to run some demos but I cannot run any, this is the message:

> Cannot create file /opt/QtSDK/Demos/4.7/chip/chip.pro.user: Permission
>   denied

To avoid this in the future, how can I set permissions to any program I install?

I'm new to using linux, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either don't install the SDK in a root-access directory, or run the program (qtcreator, etc...)with root privileges. I would choose the former solution. I generally use a folder in my home directory.

Qt SDK is standalone, so you can copy or move the whole folder to a new location which doesn't  requires root privileges.